# Railroad diagram for Python grammar

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to get better grasp on the Python grammar.
My experience is that a [railroad diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) for the grammar may be helpful.

Python documentation contains the grammar in a text form:

```
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html
```

But that is not very easy to digest for someone who is just starting with software engineering.

Anybody has a good beginners material?

There is a [Railroad Diagram Generator](http://bottlecaps.de/rr/ui) that I might be able to use, but I was not able to find an EBNF syntax for the Python grammar, that would be accepted by that generator.
A link to such a grammar would be very helpful as well.

Comment: This looks like a XY problem. You shouldn't try to understand Python's syntax by learning its formal structure as a formal grammar. If you want to look up some specialty, by all means, look at the grammar. But otherwise, you could probably better learn by using the language, or even by learning about the syntax of statements, or about the ideas behind the languages. The definition of the language's syntax as a formal grammar is a very abstract thing. That's just its nature. You _definitely shouldn't_ need an EBNF diagram to learn Python.

Comment: Out of interest, I had a quick go at this http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=6CWk4dch -- it works with the railroad diagram generator. (But may not be a perfect translation.)

Comment: @Stuart I had a go at the same thing. Looks good, although you want to replace things like `[arglist]` with `(arglist)?`, not `(arglist)*`. Generally, the only 3 things you need to change are 1) `:` to `::=` for the production rules, 2) `[...]` to `(...)?` for optional elements and 3) `#...` to `/*...*/` for comments.

Comment: @Carsten Agreed, to some extent. The OP says they want a better grasp of the Python grammar, not just Python, so it's a legitimate (albeit off-topic, asking for a link to a resource) question.

Comment: @chepner Thanks yes, here it is again http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=GvVPCJw8

Comment: @chepner I agree. Didn't even vote to close, I just wanted to offer the OP a different approach. Imho learning a language by example can show the underlying grammatical constructs, if the learner is so inclined.

Comment: @Carsten I do not think it is an XY problem.  I have a specific need - a railroad diagram for the language syntax.  I will used it as part of learning, but that is just a background. "You shouldn't try to understand Python's syntax by learning its formal structure as a formal grammar." I personally find it very enlightening to read the language grammar at some point.
Pieces of grammar (though in text form) are present on every documentation page.  But it is in text form and it is in pieces. I would like see the whole picture and as a railroad diagram.

Comment: @IlyaBobyr Then please, go on. This is a good question. I just thought you might be stuck in a too formal approach and wanted to offer a different perspective. If this works for you, please continue. If it's okay with you, I'd like to leave my comment there, even if it's not fit for your situation. It might help others who are not so formally inclined.

Comment: @chepner, thank you for converting the grammar.
Looking at it, I think, it is a bit too technical for somebody who is just starting =)
It seems that the original form is more suited for someone writing a parser.  It is terse, with as much reuse as possible.  Constants are separate rules.
I guess, it might be possible to restructure the grammar to be easier for a novice to read.  Or, maybe, Carsten is right and Python grammar is just not that good of a learning material.

Answer (score 6):

To convert the Python grammar found at, e.g., https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html, to EBNF, you basically need to do three things:

1. Replace all `#...` comments with `/*...*/` (or just delete them)
2. Use `::=` instead of `:` for defining production rules
3. Use `(...)?` to indicate optional elements instead of `[...]`.

For example, instead of

```
# The function statement
funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ['->' test] ':' suite
```

you would use

```
/* The function statement */
funcdef ::= 'def' NAME parameters ('->' test)? ':' suite
```

Comment: An interesting link that already did some of that: https://discuss.python.org/t/railroad-diagrams-for-python-grammar/1017